# NPM: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04
I removed NPM in order to install older version. (I can't exactly command which I used).
now I can't install it again.
`npm -v` output: `bash: /usr/bin/npm: /usr/bin/nodejs: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
`which npm` output: `/usr/bin/npm`

`curl -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

Output:

```
`install npm@latest
 fetching: https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-5.5.1.tgz
 module.js:544
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/npm.9881/package/bin/read-package-json.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
up to date in 0.059s
/usr/local/bin/npx -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
+ npm@5.5.1
added 1 package in 1.907s
 It worked`
```

UPD: Solved.
Remove node/nodejs/npm completely and remove all relative folders a then reinstall via NVM helped.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better way to install nodejs is via nvm. Here you can install/use multiple version of nodejs in a machine.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

then

```
nvm install $vesionNo

nvm use $versionNO

// for default 

nvm alias default node
```

Comment: I don't need to install nvm or nodejs. I have problem with npm

Comment: npm comes with nodejs you don't need install them separately I think.

Answer (score 11):

I solved it using the following simple steps in my ubuntu 18.04

1. run `which npm`
2. run `hash -r`
3. run `npm -v`

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thanks a Lot that Worked !

Answer (score 2):

In some Linux distributions, node is installed on `/usr/bin/nodejs` and not on `/usr/bin/node`.

What I did, is install nodejs-legacy, and it solved the problem. It creates a symlink from `/usr/bin/nodejs` to `/usr/bin/node`.

So, what I recommend (as the easiest solution) is to install `nodejs-legacy`:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    nodejs-legacy is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1).
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 78 not upgraded.`

Comment: Try the following commands `whereis node` and where is `nodejs` and print here the output

Comment: `node: /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz
`
`nodejs: /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/nodejs /usr/include/nodejs /usr/share/nodejs /usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz`

One more time: I have problem with NPM installing, I don't care about node/nodejs right now.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a character or a space other than the English characters from the windows user name, it can also be caused by this.

I'm talking about the installation of global packages. If you are installing a package on a specific project, it may also be caused by the lack of package.json.

Answer (score -3):

Try this command:

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

For latest version or otherwise:

```
sudo npm install -g npm@<version_no_here>
```

For specific version.

Comment: `sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
Hangup`

Comment: try installing by `sudo apt-get install npm`. If this also doesn't work then try installing node again. Follow this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You cannot run `sudo npm install -g npm@latest` since the nmp does not exist in the system.