# How to install package correctly in npm

Tags: javascript, npm

I'd like to install `nest.js`

By referring to following document.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/cli

I tried following command

`$ npm install -g @nestjs/cli`

But it returned this error.

`bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`

What happened? and How can I fix them..

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: take a look to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250971/no-such-file-or-directory-error-while-using-npm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592667/npm-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Please try re-installing [Node JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) again.